# safari: get the word under the mouse pointer

Tags: javascript, safari, range

i'm trying to find a clicked word in an onclick event handler.

```
somediv.onclick = function(event) {
    var w  = getClickedWord(event);
    alert(w)
}
```

`getClickedWord()` uses `range.moveToPoint` for msie and `event.rangeParent/offset` for gecko, but Webkit seems to support neither. Any pointers?

Comment: So show what you've got in the `getClickedWord` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try **window.getSelection()** , notice that this function returns a **Selection** object, so you should use it like following:

```
var sel = window.getSelection();
```